# Idiomatic way to turn GroupBy field back into a column when aggregating

Tags: dataset

I'm trying to find a way to convert a `GroupBy` field in a dataset into a column **after aggregation**, but I'm clearly failing to this *idiomatically*, although I found a couple of solutions, see below.

Consider the COVID-19 dataset:

```
covid = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]
```

and let's say I want to look at just the number of confirmed cases and deaths by country. It's easy to do in a *very* idiomatic way:

```
covid[GroupBy["Country"], Total, {"ConfirmedCases", "Deaths"}]
```

[image]

But let's say I now want `Spain` etc. to be a column, not a row name. I can do it with `KeyValueMap`, but it's a bit convoluted:

```
covid[GroupBy["Country"], Total, {"ConfirmedCases", "Deaths"}][
 KeyValueMap[Join[<|"Country" -> #1|>, #2] &]]
```

[image]

Another idea I had was to look at

```
covid[GroupBy["Country"] /* Values, Total, {"Country", "ConfirmedCases", 
  "Deaths"}]
```

which unfortunately doesn't work as `Country` is also aggregated,
[image]

and to try to fix it by applying each of the aggregating function in a separate query:

```
covid[GroupBy["Country"] /* Values, <|
  "Country" -> First /* "Country",
  "ConfirmedCases" -> Total /* "ConfirmedCases", 
  "Deaths" -> Total /* "Deaths"
|>]
```

which works as expected, but is also not very pleasant to the eye.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: `Transpose @ res[ GroupBy["Country"], Total, {"ConfirmedCases", "Deaths"} ]` ?

Comment: It doesn't do what I want - it returns a dataset of the form `<|"ConfirmedCases" -> <|Entity["Country", "Spain"] -> TimeSeries[...]...|>,...|>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most valuable advice is to `Normal` your dataset and look at the underlying associations instead of working with dataset directly. This instantly tells you what you want to do

[image: normalized dataset]

You see you have your countries as key with your aggregated measurements as values. Therefore, a simple `KeyValueMap` should be all it takes to transform the data and add your country key into the existing measurements

```
KeyValueMap[
 Function[{country, measures}, <|"Country" -> country, measures|>],
 covid[GroupBy["Country"], Total, {"ConfirmedCases", "Deaths"}]
 ]
```

and you get

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks @halirutan! This is very similar to my own use of `KeyValueMap`, but it's cleaner, and I like the use of explicit `Function` to document what's going on. I also didn't know that you can implicitly join associations like this: `a = <|1 -> 2, 3 -> 4|>; <|5 -> 6, a|>` produces `<|5 -> 6, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 4|>`; is it described anywhere formally? (Can't find it on Association help page).

Comment: I asked the devs if there is some documentation about this idiom. I never saw one but I use it for a long time. I guess at some point I just thought that this should work and tried it out.. along the lines "what else should Mathematica do with with `<|5 -> 6, a|>`?"